# Query returns empty in script, works perfect in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have some trouble getting data from a mysql database. 
Both the mysqli and mysql option to retrieve data using php from a database return zero rows, while they should return a couple of rows.

This is the code (mysql, the deprecated option):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","dbname") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
mysql_query($sql,$connection);
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysql_num_rows($sql));
mysql_close($connection);
```

This also did not work:

```
$data= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM name");
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($data));
```

Can anyone please help me out and explain why does not generate any result? If I pass the SQL into phpMyAdmin than it perfectly works and shows me all the data I want.

Comment: What does mysql_query return to you? Do you get any errors? Can you show the full code including how you connected to the MySQL server and database?

Comment: It's because you are trying mysqli without learning it from the **tutorial** first.

Comment: @KurtisZimmerman, it actually return that I have 0 (zero) rows. So I am not sure what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: You don't catch errors, maybe it's not a syntax pb ? Are you really connected ? Try $data = mysqli_query($connexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connexion)) ;

Comment: @user3448661 It would still help to see the code leading up to this point. The code you posted does not work in isolation, and if your connection is not successful the query certainly won't work.

Comment: @PierreGranger, thanks. Not sure if that is causing the error though. I tried your suggestion and entered the following:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
$data = mysqli_query($connetion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connetion));
echo 'ok3';
however, ok3 is not printed, the ok2 and ok1 before this code are printed. So I might have made a mistake there, but I don't see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KurtisZimmerman, I'll update the post in a sec. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Display errors like @YourCommonSense said.
I have a little doubt : mysql_query need only 1 parameter, mysqli_query need 2, not inverse.

Comment: I would definitely start by rewriting your code so you don't mix mysqli and mysql calls.

Comment: @PierreGranger actually mysql_query acceepting two, but in reverse order

Comment: @PierreGranger, thanks, I am implementing that now. Will come back with the result in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

are **essential** options in development mode.

without ability to see error messages it's just useless to try any code.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

also helps when dealing with mysqli.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the output I get:
Notice: Undefined variable: connetion in /home/adi/domains/premodded.nl/public_html/flare2.php on line 12
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/adi/domains/premodded.nl/public_html/flare2.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined variable: connetion in /home/adi/domains/premodded.nl/public_html/flare2.php on line 12
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/adi/domains/premodded.nl/public_html/flare2.php on line 12

Comment: Line 12: $data = mysqli_query($connetion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connetion));
The first issue was a typo (so stupid of me, sorry to have bothered you with that issue). And I imidetially found and fixed some more! Thank you very much Your common sense, Kurtis and Pierre! It appears to be working many thanks!

Comment: Now it comes to the first comment I left: you have to write mysqli-based code not off your head but following a tutorial

Comment: I used some examples (from tutorials) to base my work. But made some mistakes. Thanks again for your help!